# How to manipulate JPEG in cpp using chars?

Tags: c++, mpi, jpeg

I'm experiencing very strange behaviour in cpp. I'm doing some parallel  image processing using the MPI framework, and need to convert a 2D array of JSAMPLE's to a flat array of unsigned chars. 
  I am able to do this, however when I attempt to write the image from the flat array to a JPEG file the output is fuzzy, however if I set the value of the output from the flat array at the same point I read it from the 2d array it works fine.

This is very weird to me. I'ma  pretty experienced cpp developer but have not worked that much with the  JPEG library.

I think it might have something to do with memory allocation.

```
// create a flat array of unsigned chars from image
char* flat_image_array = new  char[span*Input.Width*Input.Components];
for(int j = 0; j < span; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < Input.Width * Input.Components; ++k) {
        flat_image_array[j*k+k] = imageSegment[j][k];
        // if I set output here it works fine

        //Output.Rows[j][k] =flat_image_array[j*k+k];
    }
}

for(int j = 0; j < span; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < Input.Width * Input.Components; ++k) {
        //but if I set output here the image comes out very fuzzy
        Output.Rows[j][k] = flat_image_array[j*k+k];
    }
}

std::stringstream file;
file << "Data/segment_" << (i) <<".jpg";
if(!Output.Write(file.str().c_str())){
    printf("Cannot write image\n");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `flat_image_array[j*k+k]` you want `flat_image_array[j*Input.Width+k]`. By incorrectly indexing `flat_image_array` you are leaving holes and overwriting previous values.